# How to profile an app on a remote server using the jprofiler plugin for Intellij Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, wildfly, jprofiler

I have Intellij Idea 2020, JProfiler, and the jprofiler plugin for IDEA. On a remote server, there is a WildFly 15 running the app. Currently, standalone.conf contains keys for connecting via jmx for jconsole

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9010
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=9010
...
```

I want to profile the app using JProfiler from the Idea, but I haven't found any clear instructions on how to enable profiling anywhere. As far as I understand, I need to unpack some part of JProfiler to the server and add the keys to standalone.conf for JVM? And how to connect from Idea to the profiled server? If you have step-by-step instructions, I would be very grateful

Comment: have you checked https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/ide-idea.html?

Answer (score 0):

Add a remote WildFly run configuration in IDEA, then activate the "Startup/Connection" tab in the run configuration dialog and select the "JProfiler" run type. Now the dialog shows instructions and gives you the agent VM parameter that you have to insert into the start script on the remote side.